# Create your own custom filter bar in smart filter

Tags: sapui5

I have a smart table with OperationIsReleased column in it. I had implemented a smart filter bar, where now I want to add filter option based on OperationIsReleased, i.e. if OperationIsReleased=true / OperationIsReleased=false.
I have created item list like this:
[image]

And my view.xml code is
[image]

I had Googled online but I can not find out how to refresh my table based on item list value I choose? What code should I write in controller for this? Can anyone please share some code with me where it is implemented?

(My column name coming from CDS view is OperationIsReleased, and it has Boolean values true/false.).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

you have to attach an event handler of [beforeRebindTable](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable.html#event:beforeRebindTable) of SmartTable.

Every time the **Go** button in the smart filter bar is pressed, this event will be triggered.

In the oControlEvent parameter, you will get all the existing Filters from it.

```
var aFilters = oControlEvent.getParameter("bindingParams").filters;
```

You basically need to add your additional [Filter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html) of **OperationIsReleased** to the Filters of the bindingParams.

Thank you!